# System.Type has no definition for "GetCustomAttribute" in net35

Tags: c#

The code below works without problems in net45 but i have to use it in net35 which results in the error mentioned in the title, on line 23.
I cant seem to find a way to fix it in net35 which, i think, is because that method simply doesnt exist in net35.

Any idea for an extension method or how to fix it otherwise?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using TwitchCSharp.Models;

namespace TwitchCSharp.Helpers
{
    // @author gibletto
    class TwitchListConverter : JsonConverter
    {

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var value = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType) as TwitchResponse;
            var genericArg = objectType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            var key = genericArg.GetCustomAttribute<JsonObjectAttribute>();
            if (value == null || key == null)
                return null;
            var jsonObject = JObject.Load(reader);
            value.Total = SetValue<long>(jsonObject["_total"]);
            value.Error = SetValue<string>(jsonObject["error"]);
            value.Message = SetValue<string>(jsonObject["message"]);
            var list = jsonObject[key.Id];
            var prop = value.GetType().GetProperty("List");
            if (prop != null && list != null)
            {
                prop.SetValue(value, list.ToObject(prop.PropertyType, serializer), null);
            }
            return value;
        }


        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType.IsGenericType && typeof(TwitchList<>) == objectType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
        }

        private T SetValue<T>(JToken token)
        {
            if (token != null)
            {
                return (T)token.ToObject(typeof(T));
            }
            return default(T);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the below extension method.

```
public static T GetCustomAttribute<T>(this Type type, bool inherit) where T : Attribute
{
    object[] attributes = type.GetCustomAttributes(inherit);
    return attributes.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Edit: Without any parameters.

```
public static T GetCustomAttribute<T>(this Type type) where T : Attribute
{
    // Send inherit as false if you want the attribute to be searched only on the type. If you want to search the complete inheritance hierarchy, set the parameter to true.
    object[] attributes = type.GetCustomAttributes(false);
    return attributes.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the fast reply, looks good but which is default, inherit true or false?

Comment: okay according to your edit i suppose false is default for inherit, i made the parameter optional by assigning false to it by default. thanks!