# Is there a replacement for Attribute.IsDefined in UWP apps?

Tags: c#, uwp

It seems that the static method Attribute.IsDefined is missing for UWP apps, I can navigate to the metadata for the Attribute class alright and the method is there, but the project won't compile stating that *'Attribute' does not contain a definition for 'IsDefined'* - weird (matter of fact, there are no static methods on that type at all according to IntelliSense).

I was going to query for types with a certain attribute like

```
var types = this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetTypes()
            .Where(t => Attribute.IsDefined(t, typeof (MyAttribute)));
```

and am wondering if there is a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
var types = this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(t => t.GetTypeInfo().GetCustomAttribute<MyAttribute>() != null);
```

Comment: Hmm. GetCustomAttribute accepting first argument of type 'Type' could not be found either.

Comment: This seems to work for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972197/system-type-has-no-definition-for-getcustomattribute-in-net35